# jQuery autocomplete not sending data to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having a terrible time using the jQuery autocomplete - the HTTP request isn't happening - there is no data being passed to source at all. There is no output to the console about any errors.

Has anyone got ideas?

For the record - the AJAX URL/CSRF keys etc are set up using `$.ajaxSetup()` and work fine for all the other `$.ajax()` calls.

Would appreciate all help. Thanks

```
$('.select_location_dropdown').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        data: {
             action:'location_management',
             sub_ac:'get_location_list',
             query: request.term 
        },
            success: function(data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data.search_response, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.name
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
         })

    },
    limit: 4,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
    },
    minLength: 1,
});
```

Comment: The 'error' function doesn't throw anything? I only see you using the success function. Maybe you could give us a full example (including ajaxSetup)?

Comment: As far as I know it's not an ajax error specifically - I've wrapped the function in a `if($('.select_location_dropdown.autocomplete').length) {}` as well to make sure it actually knows it exists (and it does because I've got it writing to the console).  I have added a `console.log()` after the `source: function(x,y)' which just isn't being called.

Comment: Do you have the link to the jquery script in your header? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, also take a look here and try these to see if they'll work https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Comment: Yep. Got `<script src="https://d1j0vcjilbbugt.cloudfront.net/_generic/js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script><script src="https://d1j0vcjilbbugt.cloudfront.net/_generic/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>`. If it didnt know what `.autocomplete()` was it would throw an error

Comment: But when you try to visit those links by just copy and paste you get an error....add the CDN's instead and see what happens

Comment: @JeanPaul98 still a no! Had enough about 5 hours ago so just went with the Google Places API search which better suits it anyway really (and was working within seconds). If I get it working I'll provide the world with the code that does. Nearly got it working with the Devbridge autoComplete before - but realistically I shouldn't need to use yet another plugin for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering if I ever got this working, the answer is no - not for this particular use case anyway. I am now using the [Dev Bridge jQuery Autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) for other AC use cases. After a bit of tweaking, I got it working fine.

I was considering implementing my own with an `on(function(){});` method, but decided against it.

HOWEVER, for this particular case:

Instead I am using the [Google Maps Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete), which is much better suited anyway for what we need, even if we will end up having to pay for it, it is a "needs must" kind of situation.

Below is the implemented code. It worked straight away.

```
 function initAutocomplete() {
     try {
         autocomplete_from = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
             (document.getElementById('select_location_from')), {
                 types: []
             }
         );

         autocomplete_to = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
             (document.getElementById('select_location_to')), {
                 types: []
             }
         );

         autocomplete_to.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
         autocomplete_from.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
     } catch (ex) {}
 }

 function fillInAddress() {
     // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
     var place_a = autocomplete_to.getPlace();
     var place_b = autocomplete_from.getPlace();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not added the url for the ajax call. An ajax call normally looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: {},
});
```

Comment: My bad. Could it be blocked by the browser, like say in because of CORS?

Comment: Nah - we're running the requests over jsonp. The rest are successful (we have a full order system built on it which seems to be fine. The issue here seems to be that no data is being passed to `source:function()` because even a console.log inside of it isn't firing. Weird

Comment: I have tried to make a similar setup here: https://jsfiddle.net/maxuville/98ojmtLm/ With the jsonp datatype, it produces an error that is logged on the console, otherwise if I remove the jsonp datatype, it works. Could this be what's happening on your side?

Comment: Ours wasn't producing any error - but could that be due to W3Schools' CORS config? I'm considering just getting rid of the AJAX for now and making PHP load the most popular 300 locations and throwing them into an array or something like that. An autocomplete search should never take this long to get working!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I couldn't assist.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of the extra comma at the end of your autocomplete object.

```
$('.select_location_dropdown').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        data: {
             action:'location_management',
             sub_ac:'get_location_list',
             query: request.term 
        },
            success: function(data) {
                var transformed = $.map(data.search_response, function (el) {
                    return {
                        label: el.name
                    };
                });
                response(transformed);
            },
         })

    },
    limit: 4,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

`minLength` doesn't need a comma since it's the last key value pair.

Comment: Still no :( Still not sending the data to the source function